# sudoers problem

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, sudo, ubuntu-mate

I'm using Ubuntu Mate for my raspy. I'm using my raspy to run a program 24/7, which requires to be started with sudo.

Because I don't want to do this manually, I added a script to "startup applications"... the problem is that "startup applications" get executed as `raspy` (my default user).

So, I decided to fix this with `visudo` . 
I added following entry:
`raspy ALL= (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/myscript.sh`
and rebooted.
Nothing changed- `sudo sh /usr/bin/myscript.sh` still requires a password.

After that I tried a bit around [modifying this line, verifying its syntax always by `visudo -c`...]..
I got this work:

`raspy    ALL = (raspy) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/myscript.sh`

which allows me to start the script as `raspy` without having to enter password.

The file owner is root, file owning group is root, permissions are 700 .

What have I to insert in Visudo, that I can execute my script as root ( with this `sudo sh /usr/bin/myscript.sh` ) without having to enter a password?

Comment: As a guess: `sudo sh /usr/bin/myscript.sh` runs `sh` as root, which your sudoers line did not allow.  Try running it without the `sh`

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to run something at boot, then an easy and convenient way to do this is with crontab using the `@reboot` directive.  Put it in the system crontab and it will run as root (which appears to be what you want)

Comment: sudo /usr/bin/myscript.sh  still asks for a password

Comment: @ssta , the program I need to start has to be executed after login, with an approtiate delay (that the GUI started fully)

Comment: What exactly is the script? Maybe it requires mono?

Comment: @lamatrain The script waits a minute... starts the programs with sudo and is using xdotool to do some required actions. (The programm poorly has no command line parameters to start

Comment: Why would you want to run it as `sudo sh script.sh`? You say in your question that `sudo script.sh` works. Why don't you use that then? It's i) simpler; ii) more correct; iii) shorter and iv) does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I said that this line allows to start the script as raspy without verification, but I need to start it as root

Comment: I saod that the command works but still there's a verification. ..

Comment: @leAthlon What's the output of `sudo -l`?

Comment: @muru it gives me following code:
`Matching Defaults entries for raspy on raspy-desktop:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User raspy may run the following commands on raspy-desktop:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/myscript.sh
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/myscript.sh`